# How to execute ng-repeat with orderBy filter from JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code in my html file:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="myItem in model.dataCollection|orderBy:model.sortField:model.sortReverse">
```

I am trying to find a way to iterate through the same collection in JavaScript code (in controller). The problem is that I want to be able to iterate though the collection in the same order as the order of sorted items in UI. I mean, I'm looking for something like this:

```
var sortField = model.sortField;
var sortReverse = model.sortReverse;
angular.forEach(model.dataCollection, sortField, sortReverse)
  .do(myItem => doSomethingWith(myItem));
```

What is the correct API for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the **[$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)** variable. Inject it into your controller and use it like so:

```
var items = $filter('orderBy')(model.dataCollection, model.sortField, model.sortReverse);
angular.forEach(items, function(value){
   // Do something with each value.
});
```